# when identifying an variable color in the class and I cant use it in flutter

Tags: flutter, colors

when identifying an variable color in the class and I cant use it in flutter what's the the wrong?

[image: backColor error]

when identifying an variable color in the class and I cant use it in flutter what's the the wrong?

[image: backColor error]

Comment: Give more context about what you're facing, the exact error message and stack trace if possible

Comment: Please paste the code, it will help us to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There's a key [difference between a materialColor and Color](https://elifent.tech/blog/what-is-difference-between-materialcolor-and-color-in-flutter).

Change your variable to:

```
Color backColor = const Color(0xFFFFFFFF);
```

Answer (score 0):

`Colors.white` is a type of `MaterialColor` not `Color`.

Change your variable declaration to `MaterialColor backColor = Colors.white`, or even better, just write `final backColor = Colors.white`.